# js on change event getting looped in js confirm

Tags: javascript, onchange, conflict, confirm

I have a flip toggle button().I am writing a function on change of toggle button,on change I am declaring js confirm box ,if  confirms true the button remains in changed state,else it will revert in its previous state.My issue is the function is getting iterating(looping).Please suggest

Comment: @Gerfried

/**here this flip button is 
<select id="btn">
 <option>on</option>
 <option>off</option>
</select>
 options
my code is as follows**/

  $( "#btn" ).on( "change", function() {
    var txt;
   var btnStatus= $("#btn").val();
   console.log("btnstataus>>>>>"+btnStatus);
    var r = confirm("Are you sure to change?");
    if (r == true) {
     if(btnStatus=="on"){
      $("#btn").val("on");}
     else{
      $("#btn").val("off");}
     
     }
     else {
      if(btnStatus=="on"){
      $("#btn").val("off");}
     else{
      $("#btn").val("on");}
     
    }
    
    
    });

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks quite ok. Maybe you just forgot to encapsulate your code in $(document).ready - this is necessary because otherwise your Javascript function will be loaded before the HTML DOM has been loaded - so your function will fail to access the DOM elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


 $("#btn").on("change", function() {
     var txt;
     var btnStatus = $("#btn").val();
     console.log("btnstataus>>>>>" + btnStatus);
     var r = confirm("Are you sure to change?");
     if (r == true) {
         if (btnStatus == "on") {
             $("#btn").val("on");
         } else {
             $("#btn").val("off");
         }
     } else {
         if (btnStatus == "on") {
             $("#btn").val("off");
         } else {
             $("#btn").val("on");
         }
     }
 });

});
```

Here is a working sample of your code:
https://plnkr.co/edit/AdzcN04F1fsLe9xw454j?p=preview

Comment: on click it's ok. But on sliding this button it's getting looped.

ref.jquery-mobile flip toggle switch.

<select id="" name="" data-role="slider" >
        <option value="off"></option>
        <option value="on"></option>
              
          </select>

@Gerfried

Comment: Can you please extend my plunkr sample?